# I see veiw ids but can't use them

Tags: android, automation, androidviewclient

While using latest 5.4.4 AndroidViewClient and 4.4.2 KitKat Android device I see desirable view ids with dump-simple.py provided file but when I try to use these ids with findViewByIdOrRaise method I receive an exception:

com.dtmilano.android.viewclient.ViewNotFoundException: Couldn't find View with ID='android.widget.ImageView fourier.milab:id/infoIcon' in tree with root=ROOT

I tried several times, no typos etc.
So how can I use (touch etc.) these views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) generate the script template for you

```
$ culebra -VC -d on -o /tmp/kitkat.py
```

the edit generated `/tmp/kitkat.py` script to suit your needs, for example if you want to touch the QSB bar, after the line with the `findViewByIdOrRaise()` add the `touch()`

```
# class=android.widget.RelativeLayout
com_android_launcher___id_qsb_search_bar = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise("com.android.launcher:id/qsb_search_bar")
com_android_launcher___id_qsb_search_bar.touch()
```

Comment: It worked but: 
I added 
try:
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME'], 'src'))
except:
    pass
code to code generated by culebra. Without this it presented an exception: ImportError: No module named dtmilano
I suppose you adding this for future culebra versions
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because of the app package I has set in my config file. if you have two build variants, make sure the app running has the correct package name stated in the config file